# Obtener datos de key en SharedPreferences Listener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences

En Kotlin, intento configurar un Listener para que ante cualquier cambio en mi SharedPreferences realice cierta acción, ya he logrado que detecte los cambios, el detalle es que no encuentro como extraer los datos de `p1`, es decir como obtengo los nuevos valores:

```kotlin
override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(p0: SharedPreferences?, p1: String?){
        Log.i(TAG,p1.toString())
}
```

Al realizar lo anterior solo obtengo las keys, pero no encuentro como acceder a los nuevos valores.
Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [onSharedPreferenceChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener#onsharedpreferencechanged) Es llamada cuando una Shared
> Preference ha sido cambiada, agregada o removida.

Si deseas obtener el valor de la preferencia dentro de [onSharedPreferenceChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener#onsharedpreferencechanged) usa la llave que recibes para obtener el valor.

Suponiendo que tu valor se guardo con la llave "valorCarlos", puedes realizar lo siguiente para obtener el valor:

```
override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
    when (key) {
        "valorCarlos" -> {
            var valor = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "")
            Log.i(TAG, "El valor guardado es : "  + valor)
        }
    }
}
```

en el caso de tu código para obtener cualquier valor que fue cambiado, agregado o removido, realizarías los siguiente:

```
override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(p0: SharedPreferences?, p1: String?){
        Log.i(TAG, sharedPreferences.getString(p1, ""))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Con el key deberías poder acceder al valor de shared sin problema

```kotlin
val sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
sharedPrefs.getString(p1, "")
```